# FreeCodeCamp Javascript Challenge [Mutation] What's wrong with my solution?

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't my solution work for this challenge?  https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/mutations

> Return true if the string in the first element of the array contains
> all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array.

My solution is naive and iterative. It attempts to compare the second string against the first.

```
 function mutation(arr) {
  var first = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var second = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    if (first.indexOf(second[i]) === -1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    } 
  } 
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Comment: You're not going to make me google, are you? What's the challenge, what is your code's expected behavior, and what's its actual behavior?

Comment: Are you calling the function somewhere and making use of the return values?

Comment: Yes. The call: mutation(["hello", "hey"]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't Need loop because your array size  will be 2  anyway :

```js
 function mutation(arr) {


     return arr[1].toLowerCase().split('').map((ch)=>arr[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(ch)>=0).every((e)=>e)
}

console.log(
    mutation(["hello","Hello"])
)
console.log(
    mutation(["Alien", "line"])
)
console.log(
    mutation(["hello","hey"])
)
```

## Explain Code with `mutation(["Alien", "line"])` as Example :

- `arr[1].toLowerCase().split('')` => split `line` to array `['l','i','n','e']`
- `['l','i','n','e'].map((ch)=>arr[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(ch)>=0)` for each character , check if it exists on the 1st elememt `arr[0]`
  ==> The result will be `[true,true,true,true]`
- Apply the **AND Logic Operator** among that result `[true,true,true,true].every((e)=>e)` ==> `true & true & true & true`
- The result is true

Comment: You need `.every` here, not `reduce`.

Comment: I update the answer & i explain my solution .. it is opportunity to learn :)

Comment: @georg : Thank you for reminder .. UPDATED ! `.every((e)=>e)`

Answer (score 0):

You need here `While` Loop better than `for` Loop :

```js
 function mutation(arr) {
    var j=0,first = arr[0].toLowerCase(),second = arr[1].toLowerCase();
   
    while(j<second.length && first.indexOf(second[j])>=0){
            j++;
     }
     return !(j===second.length-1)
  
}
  //-------- SAMPLES
console.log(
  mutation(["hello", "Hello"])
)

console.log(
  mutation(["hello", "hey"])
)

console.log(
  mutation(["Alien", "line"])
)
```